# Why arguments.callee.caller is not working?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code looks like this:

```
var b = function() {
    try {
        console.log('b is called')
        console.log(arguments.callee.caller.toString())
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
var a = function() {
    setTimeout(b, 0)
}
a()
```

And why the output shows that `arguments.callee.caller` is `null`?

Comment: What result did you expect? (Certainly not `a`, because `a` didn't call `b`...) ["If the function `f` was invoked by the top level code, the value of `f.caller` is null, otherwise it's the function that called `f`."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller)

Comment: Eh, you're right!But if I want to trace the call stack in code, how should I do?

Comment: But...in this case `b` is the only thing in the stack, because it is called by the system (via `setTimeout`), not by `a`. So what result do you want?

Comment: `I want to trace the call stack` Why? What's the actual problem you try to solve here?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem just I thought when I learn the javascript

Comment: using `arguments.callee` is highly discouraged nowadays, `callee` even deprecated as far as I know. But when do actually you need a stack-trace? Usually when errors occur. And voila, `Error` objects provide a stack trace. *Also, check out the debugger in your browser; they are really good these days.* If you just want to trace function calls, use `console.log()`. And if your function `b` needs to know who called it, to do its job, then this sounds like a function argument to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy when you're working with thousands of lines of code to forget *what* you've programmed a few years back.

The issue is that when you call a function from the `console` or via a *global variable* then `arguments.callee.caller === null`. You can use the code below in any function which is very useful for debugging purposes.

```
console.log((arguments.callee.caller === null) ? 'Console or Global Variable Declaration' : arguments.callee.caller.toString().split('function ')[1].split('(')[0]);
```

If you're having trouble tracking down something like a global variable then:

1. Make a copy of your code (usually your root directory).
2. Go to whatever JavaScript file contains your global variables (they should *always* be declared *before* any named functions).
3. Either comment them out or set them to `false` one at a time if they call the function you're having trouble with.

Comment: "It's easy when you're working with thousands of lines of code, to forget _what_ you've programmed a few years back."—TBH, I rarely remember after a few days.